# Dijkstra algorithm: how are set and sum used?

Tags: python

I don't understand this line of code

```
self.vertices = set(sum(([e.start, e.end] for e in edges2), []))
```

from [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Python)

`print(edges2)` shows:

```
[Edge(start='a', end='b', cost=7), Edge(start='a', end='c', cost=9), 
 Edge(start='a', end='f', cost=14), Edge(start='b', end='c', cost=10), 
 Edge(start='b', end='d', cost=15), Edge(start='c', end='d', cost=11), 
 Edge(start='c', end='f', cost=2), Edge(start='d', end='e', cost=6), 
 Edge(start='e', end='f', cost=9)]
```

I understand `sum` as adding a list of numbers. When I test in Python:

```
dd = ["a","b","c","d"]
sum(dd)
```

I get:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for `+`: '`int`' and '`str`'

How is `sum` called in this case, when start and end are not numbers?

Comment: It's abusing `sum()` as a list flattener. More idiomatic Python could use `self.vertices = set(); for e in edges2: self.vertices.update(e)` or  `set(itertools.chain(*edges2))` or `import operator; reduce(operator.add, [...])` ...

Comment: I didn't understand how sum was used since sum for a list is adding integers.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Let me know if anything else I should add.

Comment: @kay00 That looks much better. Remember when writing a question that we can't read your mind. You need to be clear about exactly what you need so we can make sure we're actually helping with the things you need us to help with.

Comment: @MorganThrapp right I don't want to waste anyone's time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though this code examines all the edges in `edges2` and makes a list (really a set) of each vertex that is touched by one of those edges.

```
for e in edges2
```

is going to iterate through each element of edges2

```
([e.start, e.end] for e in edges2)
```

uses the iteration through edges2 to create a tuple. The elements of this tuple are lists comprised of 2 elements (i.e. e.start, e.end). One could imagine a sample such tuple as being `(['a','b'],['b','c'],['c','d'],['d','a'])`

```
 sum(([e.start, e.end] for e in edges2), [])
```

sums the lists in the tuple, to provide a single, flattened list (i.e. `['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'a']`). Here using an empty list as the second argument to sum indicates that we're summing lists. Although, if you look at sum.__doc__, this does not seem to be the way the sum function was intended to be used.

finally,

```
 set( ... )
```

takes the list and converts it to a set. This eliminates duplicate entries, so no vertex appears more than once (i.e. `['a','b','c','d']`)

A long way to do this might be:

```
  vertex_pairs = ([e.start, e.end] for e in edges2)
  vertex_list = sum(vertex_pairs, [])
  vertex_set = set(vertex_list)
  self.vertices = vertex_set
```

(Note: I originally used integers as vertex labels, but switched to characters to avoid confusion)

Comment: So you are saying e.start and e.end are numbers even though printing out edges2 shows [Edge(start='a', end='b', cost=7), Edge(start='a', end='c', cost=9), Edge(start='a', end='f', cost=14), Edge(start='b', end='c', cost=10), Edge(start='b', end='d', cost=15), Edge(start='c', end='d', cost=11), Edge(start='c', end='f', cost=2), Edge(start='d', end='e', cost=6), Edge(start='e', end='f', cost=9)]

Comment: @kay00 - I was using numbers as an example of a way to label vertices. It works the same for letters. The `sum` function is summing the lists in the tuple, not the actual numeric values. Try z = (['a','b'],['b','c'],['c','d'],['d','a']) and then sum(z,[]). This will give ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'a'].